# Tortoisesvn doesn't recognize changed files after update

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn

After I updated my tortoise-svn client, I haven't been able to commit.

I have modified some files, but for some reason it seems like subversion does not see these changes, so when I try and commit, I get the message that nothing has changed so there is nothing to commit.

when I compare the files with TortoiseMerge, there IS a difference.

What is wrong and how do I fix it?

Comment: Maybe changed files are in svn:ignore list.

Comment: Nope that's not it. I tried to re-install a couple of times, and then manually edit the changed files. It seemed to work, but there is no guarantee that I got all the changes right.

Answer (score 0):

I observed such behavior when the working copy was located on a network drive.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the [FAQ](http://tortoisesvn.net/faq.html#detectmodification).

Answer (score 0):

Recently I've stumbled on this situation with plain CLI `svn` command. The reason was, someone changed the file both in working copy *and* `.svn/text-base` directory...