# Force refresh of "unchanged" files using TortoiseSVN

Tags: svn, vb6, tortoisesvn

I have a VB6 project which when I opened it the VisualBasic IDE thought it would be fine to remove all controls that it didn't have a reference for.

For some reason TortoiseSVN does not recognize these changes despite a time stamp change on all effected files and a very obvious change when you run a diff.  I can't revert the files in question because they are not recognized as changed, if I force a recursive update it skips them because they are already "latest"...  I don't want to blow away my folder and start over if I don't have to.  All files are on my C drive.

Suggestions on how I can force a refresh on these files?

(a similar, unresolved question: [Tortoisesvn doesn't recognize changed files after update](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8167250/tortoisesvn-doesnt-recognize-changed-files-after-update))

Comment: This doesn't make sense. If the local files are different from repository files, they are always marked as modified. In theory, timestamp doesn't affect the diff process.

Comment: @CiganoMorrisonMendez - I know it doesn't make sense, which is why I posted the issue.  I was never able to get SVN to recognize them as changed, despite size/contents/timestamp changes on the files.  In the end I just blew away my local copy and got it fresh from SVN.  I have over a dozen other SVN repositories which all work without issue...